# Error while locating XML file

Tags: php, xml

I've started with very basic example in order to understand how to read data from XML. So, `test.xml` and `index.php` are located in the root directory. The following code of `index.php` returns `Failed Loading XML`. Why this actually happens?

```
   <?php
            $source = './test.xml';

            loadXml($source);


        function loadXml($source){ 
            /*
             * Checks for xml file errors
             */
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

            $xml = simplexml_load_file($source);
            if (!$xml){
                echo "Failed Loading XML\n";
                foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error){
                    echo "\t", $error->message;
                }
            } else {
                    print_r($xml);
            }
            // etc....
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Before you load the xml, check to see if the file really does exist first. I know you're saying it is there, but it is always worthwhile to do this check just in case: `if (is_file($source))`
2. The XML may be malformed. You can check it with online services such as http://www.xmlvalidation.com/. One of the easiest things to check for though is that there is no white space before the XML declaration `<?xml version='1.0'?>`